# Flashes in Windows Explorer and Random Restarts of the Taskbar (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-explorer, taskbar

I have a Dell Precision 5540 with Core I7-9850H 32GB Ram 512GB SSD NVIDIA Quadro T1000 4GB 15.6″ Inch FHD running Windows 10 22H2.

Recently, I have been noticing **flashes in Windows Explorer** and **random restarts of the taskbar**; all its icons disappear suddenly and load again.

As you can see in the videos, the Control Panel window flashes (Not Responding) momentarily upon simple scrolling up and down and sometime its icon in the taskbar replicates to another instance and the new instance disappears instantly.

Video 1 (Flashing Window)
https://streamable.com/v8ufx5

Video 2 (Duplicating Icon)
https://streamable.com/qfy5zr

**Additional Observations:**

1- I previously configure my touchpad’s three-finger gesture to be a middle click. It is functional anywhere; in Chrome to close tabs, or in Windows Explorer to open new windows if the taskbar icon is middle-clicked. But I am no longer able to close a Windows Explorer window by clicking its thumbnail preview as I used to do unless I click on an empty area on the taskbar beforehand. It seems like the preview doesn’t get the necessary focus to perform the action.
https://streamable.com/0sn0j1

2- The battery icon and sometimes the sound icon disappear from the system tray.

**What I Did:**

1- Updated the two graphics drivers (intel and Nvidia) to the latest drivers published in their official websites, making sure all settings are reset during installation. Result: None.

2- Reverted to the driver versions published on Dell’s website for my laptop. Result: None.

3- Reset my bios to its default values. Result: None.

4- Set “Visual Effects” in System Properties Performance Option to “Adjust for best performance”. Result: None.

5- Disabled Hardware-accelerated GPU Scheduling. Result: None.

*I cannot remember that I have done any recent changes in my system except for the usual updates of Chrome, Thunderbird, and Avast AV.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is in way an expected behavior or bug in Windows 10, and things you have tried have not worked.

Try a Windows 10 Repair Install using the Keep Everything Option.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally
> answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

If the "standard" Repair Install does not work, back everything up and install Windows 10 fresh.

If you can (if your computer will do it) upgrade to Windows 11.

Comment: I ran DDU in safemode to uninstall both drivers and reinstalled them in normal mode. But, unfortunately, nothing changed.
I also ran
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
SFC /scannow

I got Windows "Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations."

Weirdly enough, when I repaired my Windows with a recent installation media (en-us_windows_10_consumer_editions_version_22h2_updated_feb_2024_x64_dvd_c937d96c), everything came back to normal.

Comment: So if you did a repair as I suggested, consider accepting my answer.

Comment: My apologies, John. I truly thank you for your help, but the system displays 
"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: You do not need any reputation to accept an answer (just for upvotes)

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks again, John.